# How do I make an image not affect the scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image that follows my mouse using the following:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $(".image").css({
    left: e.pageX + 50,
    top: e.pageY + 50
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="Media/example.png" />
```

The problem arises when my mouse is on the bottom or right hand side of the website as the image that follows my mouse goes off-screen (as intended) and because of this, a scroll bar appears on the website.

I don't want the picture following the mouse to affect how much you are able to scroll. How do I fix this?

Comment: Would setting your body to overflow: hidden: be considered as a solution for you?

Comment: Considering the image is offset to the bottom-right of the mouse position, it's going to be 'off screen' when you're in the bottom-right corner. What behaviour would you like to happen in this case? Should it simply 'disappear' off the edge, and not expand the window?

Comment: Thank you both for the help! I was trying to make a full-screen div with the overflow: hidden;. That didn't work out too well. I'm happy that this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to disappear off the screen rather than expanding the window, what you're looking for is to apply **[`overflow: hidden`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)** to `body`. An `overflow` of `hidden` both clips the content and hides the scrollbars:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $(".image").css({
    left: e.pageX + 50,
    top: e.pageY + 50
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: 10%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/100" />
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sure thing (once the timer runs out, I will be eligible to do so). I'm new to this website so it's telling me I can't upvote you, I'll try and remember to come back!

Comment: Yes, welcome to StackOverflow! Well-asked questions usually get answered rather quickly :) You'd be surprised how many people don't mark questions as resolved - there are literally millions of unresolved questions here. Marking questions as resolved helps future readers knows that the accepted answer does indeed resolve the problem outlined (which is helpful when there are multiple answers, and some don't). I'd also recommend checking out the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and some of the when you get  a chance :)